# Face ID auth freezes application after canEvaluatePolicy call

Tags: ios, swift, localauthentication, face-id

In my application, I attempt to login with Face ID using `evaluatePolicy`, and after 1 or 2 logins, I get an error in the callback. In that error, I call an async completion handler which calls another and eventually it calls `canEvaluatePolicy`. My app then freezes, allowing no further interaction with the UI. Why would this be happening? Does it have something to do with thread-safety? Some sample code that recreates this issue, can be found [here](https://github.com/tfrank64/FaceID-Issue)

Here is a code snippet from that sample code for reference:

```
    let localAuthenticationContext = LAContext()
    if localAuthenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) {

        localAuthenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "To access secure data") { success, evaluateError in

            if success {
                print("Success")
            } else {
                print("Face ID Error")
                let context = LAContext()
                let status = context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil)
                print("Status: \(status)")
            }
        }
    }
```

I've been using Xcode 9.1 Beta 2 with the iPhone X simulator.

Comment: The documentation very clearly says not to do what you're doing, and why. And it tells you that what is happening is exactly what will happen.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I guess I need a workaround to use `canEvaluatePolicy` after a failed login, in order to setup my UI properly. Since the docs also say not to save the value for `canEvaluatePolicy`.

Comment: Weirdly, my code doesn't and never did have problems with devices that support Touch ID. Just iPhone X at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, I can only get the deadlock to occur if the error from `evaluatePolicy` is ["Lost connection to coreauthd."](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6086985273835520)